# Nesting NetGraph and accessing inner NetPorts

Tags: neural-networks

Can `NetGraph` be nested and how does once access the inner ports of such a nested network? The documentation does (to my knowledge) not specify this and there are no examples of this being done.

Answer (score 4):

`NetGraph` can be nested even though the documentation does not mention this directly and only shows that using `NetChain` inside `NetGraph` is possible.

Take for instance this simple net that computes the total of its inputs

```
simpleNet = 
NetGraph[{TotalLayer[]}, {NetPort["Input1"] -> 1,NetPort["Input2"] -> 1}]
```

[image: simpleNet]

and apply it to some input

```
simpleNet[<|"Input1" -> 1, "Input2" -> 2|>]
(*3*)
```

---

The following `NetGraph` builds on top of the previous `simpleNet` to compute the sine of the sum of the two inputs

```
complicatedNet = 
NetGraph[<|"Net" -> simpleNet,"f" -> ElementwiseLayer[Sin]|>, {"Net" -> "f"}]
```

[image: complicatedNet]

to try it out evaluate

```
complicatedNet[<|"Input1" -> N@Pi, "Input2" -> 0|>]
(*-8.74228*10^-8*)
```

Notice that `NetGraph` automatically handles the in- and outputs. To take manual control over the way things get connected we can make use of `NetPort`. The documentation of `NetPort` again is a bit vague and only states that

> `NetPort[{"name","port"}]`  represents the specified port for the layer
>   with the specified name.

In terms of the outermost `NetGraph` the inner `Netgraph` is just another layer so that we can access its ports via the syntax above.

The following net computes the sine of the sum of the first two inputs and multiplies the result with a third input

```
nestedNet = 
NetGraph[<|"Net" -> complicatedNet, "Plus" -> ThreadingLayer[Times]|>,    
{NetPort["1"] -> NetPort["Net", "Input1"], 
 NetPort["2"] -> NetPort["Net", "Input2"], 
{NetPort["3"], NetPort["Net", "Output"]} -> "Plus"}]
```

[image: nestedNet]

The syntax to evaluate this net on some input is

```
nestedNet[<|"1" -> N@(Pi/4), "2" -> N@(Pi/4), "3" -> 3|>]
(*3.*)
```

Notice the names of the in- and outputs in the resulting Net.